# Dividing Layout vertically in two equal parts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have to divide the screen into 2 equal parts vertically.But i am not able to find where I am doing wrong!! I have used layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight="1" for both LinearLayout but still result is same.

I checked this post also

[How to split the screen with two equal LinearLayouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424904/how-to-split-the-screen-with-two-equal-linearlayouts)

[How to divide screen into three parts vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988994/how-to-divide-screen-into-three-parts-vertically)

Still I was not able to achieve it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/profileImBg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileIm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/profileImage" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        style="@style/cardStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

            app:columnCount="2"
            app:rowCount="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="#757575"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="0"

                />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="#757575"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_column="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="Contact Number"
                android:textColor="#757575"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="1"

                />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contactNumber"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="#757575"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_column="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="2"
                app:layout_row="1" />






        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try weight 50 in both layouts instead of 1

Comment: This is not working either

Comment: even after removing cardstyle it is not working

Answer (score 4):

Using Weight attribute you can achieve, use below code for same.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
     <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dp"/>
     <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

try using the new Library from the [Percent Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent):

```
 dependencies{
     compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.0'
 }
```

Then:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
 <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/frame1"
          app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">

     </FrameLayout>

     <FrameLayout
          android:layout_below="@+id/frame1"
          app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">

      </FrameLayout>

 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

This also has support for `PercentFrameLayout`

So in your case this would look like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
 <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/frame1"
          app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">

          <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/profileIm"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
               android:src="@drawable/profileImage" />

     </FrameLayout>

     <FrameLayout
          app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
          android:layout_below="@+id/frame1"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">

          <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
               android:id="@+id/card_view"
               style="@style/cardStyle"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout

                 ... and so on ...>

             </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

          </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
      </FrameLayout>

 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried using PercentRelativeLayout but now both of the layouts are overlapping with each other

Comment: @Zero see update i was missing `layout_below` flag to tell the second frame to display below. hope this solves it for you

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_weight` and `android:weightSum` to divide layouts into equal parts. It is important to set `layout_width` as `0dp` on children to make it work as intended.

**On parent layout**:

Set `weightSum` of parent Layout as `2` (`android:weightSum="2"`)

**On the child layout**:

Set `layout_width` as `0dp` (`android:layout_width="0dp"`)
Set `layout_weight` as `1` [half of weight sum] (`android:layout_weight="1"`)

```
<!-- Parent layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <!-- Child layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ......
            >
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            style="@style/cardStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
    ....
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: This solution is not working there is no difference in ratio whether we keep 1 or  50. It is same